# How to fix 403 "Access Denied" response when trying to access files from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, django-storage

**The Problem**

When trying to load the static content for my web application from a Google Cloud Storage bucket, a handful of files return a 403 response code, while all others are downloaded successfully.

**The Setup**

The application is a Django-powered (2.1.3) Python (3.7) application hosted on Google App Engine, using service account credentials that have been given Editor permissions in IAM. We use Bootstrap 3.3.7 for our frontend, hosting its source files in our GCS bucket, and the django-storages (1.7.1) plugin for interfacing with the GCS API.

The troublesome files are the Glyphicon images provided with Bootstrap, as well as a CSS map. All other Bootstrap resources load without issue. I've tried:

1. Giving the service account numerous combinations of IAM permissions
2. Recreating the service account and the key file we use to authenticate it
3. Disabling and reenabling the Google Cloud Storage API
4. Creating a new bucket and reloading all the static files to it using the service account credentials
5. Granting AllUsers read access to the problematic files (as the policies are currently set)
6. Granting AllUsers read access to the entire bucket

The last fix attempt (#6) did enable access to the glyphicons, but isn't an acceptable solution.

**The Code**

Static file path/GCP configuration in our `settings.py`:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
# If on GAE, use STATIC_ROOT; local, use STATICFILES_DIRS
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if os.getenv('GAE_ENV', '').startswith('standard'):
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
else:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')]

# Media url
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media/')

# Google Cloud Platform Settings (Storage & Authentication)
# Authentication
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'conf/vwa.json')
GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'conf/vwa.json')
)
# File Storage
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('GS_BUCKET_NAME', '')
# Static Storage
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
```

IAM policy for the bucket:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:SERVICEACCOUNTADDRESS"
      ], 
      "role": "roles/storage.admin"
    }, 
    {
      "members": [
        "projectEditor:PROJECTNAME", 
        "projectOwner:PROJECTNAME"
      ], 
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner"
    }, 
    {
      "members": [
        "projectViewer:PROJECTNAME"
      ], 
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketReader"
    }
  ], 
  "etag": "CAI="
}
```

ACL policy for the bucket:

```
[
  {
    "entity": "project-editors-649435531377",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "649435531377",
      "team": "editors"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-owners-649435531377",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "649435531377",
      "team": "owners"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-viewers-649435531377",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "649435531377",
      "team": "viewers"
    },
    "role": "READER"
  }
]
```

IAM policy for the glyphicons:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "projectOwner:PROJECTNAME", 
        "projectEditor:PROJECTNAME", 
        "serviceAccount:SERVICEACCOUNTADDRESS", 
        "allUsers"
      ], 
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyObjectOwner"
    }, 
    {
      "members": [
        "projectViewer:PROJECTNAME", 
        "allAuthenticatedUsers"
      ], 
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyObjectReader"
    }
  ], 
  "etag": "CAQ="
}
```

ACL policy for the glyphicons:

```
[
  {
    "entity": "project-owners-649435531377",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "649435531377",
      "team": "owners"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-editors-649435531377",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "649435531377",
      "team": "editors"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-viewers-649435531377",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "649435531377",
      "team": "viewers"
    },
    "role": "READER"
  },
  {
    "email": "SERVICEACCOUNTADDRESS",
    "entity": "user-SERVICEACCOUNTADDRESS",
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "allAuthenticatedUsers",
    "role": "READER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "allUsers",
    "role": "OWNER"
  }
]
```

I expect that the problematic files should be properly downloaded, but the actual behavior is a 403 response code. I appreciate any and all help, as well as suggestions for improving my question. Thanks!

Comment: You have an absolute mess with both your IAM policies and Bucket ACLs. Never assign `allUsers` or `allAuthenticatedUsers` in an IAM policy. All you needed to do was add `allUsers` to the objects in the bucket that you want public. I strongly recommend that you create a separate bucket for public files for your website. Make the entire bucket public and don't play with individual permissions. Only put objects in the public bucket that you want the world to read.

Comment: @JohnHanley the mess is a result of my attempts to gain access for the service account, so I agree. `allUsers` as part of the objects' IAM or ACL policy doesn't give access. In the GCS console, the objects are marked as public, but still do not load in the application. Your recommendation would be my last-ditch effort. I'd prefer none of the files to be accessible outside of the application.

Comment: @zlunchbox Where you able to arrive at a solution? I am trying to serve a GC storage bucket using `allAuthenticatedUsers`. Ideally, all users would be managed by the Django, Flask, or FastAPI app, but I am ok with getting `allAuthenticatedUsers` up and running first.